# How to get the list latest entries from the database table for list of values for the specific column?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a database table where there is a column hostname and few other columns.
in hostname, there are many instances of rows with same hostnames.

> Ex. 192.0.0.1 has 40 entries and 192.0.0.2 has 35 entries and so on.

Is it possible to get the list of latest entries for each hostname? meaning in the result i should get  one latest for 192.0.0.1 and one latest for  192.0.0.2 and so on.

I tried with

```
SELECT host,cluster,region,service 
  FROM system
 WHERE host IN ("171.33.64.158","171.33.64.159")  
 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

but the output contains only one row which is probably the first row of the entire result.

Can anyone please help me in this requirement?

Thanks,
Swapnil

Comment: How do you define latest? Do you have a timestamp column or something similar?

Comment: Is your DBMS Oracle as tagged or MySQL as it suggests from the format of the query?

Comment: `LIMIT 1` will only get one row.

Comment: @PaulT. Oracle does not support the `LIMIT` keyword.

Comment: @Mureinik the latest for me would be the last entry for the particular hostname in the table. My database is MySQL

Comment: "last entry for the particular hostname"  It is a fundamental of relational databases that rows are 'unordered'.  They are like balls in a basket.  There is no concept of 'last' until you SELECT with an ORDER BY clause.  Without an ORDER BY there will be, of course, a 'last' row listed. But which specific row it is will be totally random.

Comment: @MT0 ... Thanks for that info, I was only going by the presented query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select host,cluster,region,service
from (
   SELECT host,cluster,region,service, row_number() over (partition by host order by id 
      desc) as r_num
   FROM system
   WHERE host IN ("171.33.64.158","171.33.64.159"))
where r_num = 1;
```

Thanks

Comment: this query is not working for me. I am using MySQL database.

Answer (score -1):

For proper ordering you need to convert the IP address into decimal equivalent. I would suggest a function like this:

```
FUNCTION IP2Decimal(IP IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC IS
    DecimalIp NUMBER; 
BEGIN

   SELECT SUM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(IP, '\d+', 1, LEVEL) * POWER(256, 4-LEVEL))
   INTO DecimalIp
   FROM dual 
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4;
   RETURN DecimalIp;    

END IP2Decimal;
```

Then your query could be this:

```
SELECT hostname,
  FIRST_VALUE(host) OVER (ORDER BY IP2Decimal(host)),
  FIRST_VALUE(cluster) OVER (ORDER BY IP2Decimal(host)),
  FIRST_VALUE(region) OVER (ORDER BY IP2Decimal(host)),
  FIRST_VALUE(service) OVER (ORDER BY IP2Decimal(host))
FROM system
GROUP BY hostname;
```

Comment: @AlmirCampos, indeed the given query in the question does not correspond with the text. I tried to give a solution that matches the **question** rather than the (not working) query.